# Cannot load zmg.node after webpack bundle

Tags: node.js, vue.js, webpack, electron, zeromq

I'm using the zerorpc package within an Electron-Vue project as a client to communicate with a remove server. Before using webpack to bundle the project, I was able to call these functions both in the main process and in the renderer process of Electron but after using vue command line to create a project which automatically adds in webpack and babel, it cannot load the module.

I've created a basic Vue.js project using its command line interface and then installed vue-electron-builder plugin and selected electron 5 using the following commands:

```
vue create myproject
yarn install
vue add electron-builder
yarn install zerorpc --save
yarn electron:serve
```

Some had suggested to rebuild the zeromq library against the Electron headers for a similar problem but that didn't solve the problem.

When I run `yarn electron:serve`, it finishes the normal serving procedure successfully but faces an error it's bundling the main process:

```
error  in ./node_modules/zeromq/build/Release/zmq.node

Module parse failed: Unexpected character '' (1:0)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
(Source code omitted for this binary file)
```